# How to change Koa's http status code for non-defined routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, koa

What would be best way to change default http status code and response body if somebody accesses undefined (not set) route on Koa server?

Right now Koa returns 404 status and 'Not Found' text in the body. I would like to change it to **501 (Not implemented)** just to prevent collisions when actual existing API's response is 404.

Answer (score 2):

You can add wildcard route to the end of your `koa-router`
It will looks like that:

```
router
  .get('/', async ctx => ctx.body = 'existed route')
  .all('/*', async ctx => ctx.status = 501)

app.use(router.routes())
```

`GET` request to `/` will return `'existed route'` string. All other routes will return `501` status

Hope it will help